# What is the <80><f5>X keycode?

Tags: key-bindings

I created the following mapping.

```
vmap <leftmouse> <cmd>echom getchar()<cr>
```

I then enter visual mode, switch to select mode by pressing `<c-g>`, and then drag the mouse.

After exiting visual mode, and entering `:messages`, I see the following output:

```
<80><f5>X
```

This occurs in Vim and Neovim.

This is intended as a minimal example to reproduce a character I saw in a different context for a Neovim plugin I've developed.

I'd like to add handling, but I'm not sure which keycode this corresponds to or what string representation I can use (e.g., `"\<keycode>`") for comparison.

Comment: > "This looks more like a comment than an answer."
@D.BenKnoble, I think your comment in reference to an answer was posted to the wrong location (as this is a question).

Comment: I’ll delete it; what actually happened (and you couldn’t know this now) is that I commented on an answer which I subsequently converted to a comment on this question. The poster appears to have deleted their comment, leaving mine looking, well, absurd :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape sequence <80><f5>X corresponds to <K_SPECIAL> <KS_SELECT> <KE_FILLER>.
This is used internally by Vim to enable the Select mode after a mapping or menu is executed. You can refer to the following:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/getchar.c#L2667
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/keymap.h#L88